# Cant access and assign values into composite table of a many to many relationship through front end?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I'm trying to develop an ASP.NET MVC application using C# and EF with code-first approach.

I have two classes: Actors and Movies which have many-to-many relationships (an Actor can be in many Movies, a Movie can have many Actors).

Everything is working properly, but I can not access the intermediate (MoviesActors) table through a view (this table is generated automatically as a result of the many-to-many relationship between Actors and Movies). I want to access this table so that I could assign the correct primary keys (For example: I want to assign the correct actor to a movie and vice versa) to determine things like "In which movies does a particular actor have played role?" and "What is the star cast of a particular movie?

These are my models:

```
public class Actors
{
public Actors()
{
    this.mvz = new HashSet<Movies>();
}

public int Id { get; set; }
public string actor_name { get; set; }
public string country { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Movies> mvz { get; set; }
}
```

This is Movies Model

```
  public class Movies
  {
  public Movies()
  {
    this.actz = new HashSet<Actors>();
  }

public int Id { get; set; }
public string Movie_title { get; set; }
public string genre { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Actors> actz { get; set; }
}
```

AS you can see both models have many to many relationship in between them and as a result a third table is generated in database that contains the composite keys.

Everything works properly up to this point, But the issue is that i can not assign values to the composite key table via front end, Although i can assign these values manually from the back-end.

I would like to ask if my approach is correct or not, I mean in a real world application do we have to access the composite key table and assign values, or is there any better approach to solve this issue?

Here is the controller:

```
 public ActionResult DataEntry()
 {
  return View();
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Add(??? mva)
 {
_context.act.Add(mva.act);
_context.mvz.Add(mva.mvz);
_context.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index","Actors");
 }
```

And here is the view:

```
   @model 
   Many_To_Many_Relationship_Latest.ViewModel.MoviesActorsViewModel
   @{
   ViewBag.Title = "DataEntry";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }

   <h5>Assign Actors to a particular Movie From Here</h5>

   @using (Html.BeginForm("Add","MoviesActors"))
  {
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(a=> a.mvz.Id)
@Html.TextBoxFor(a=> a.mvz.Id, new { @class="forcontrol"})
</div>
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(a => a.act.Id)
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.act.Id, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
 }
```

Here is the ViewModel

```
  public class MoviesActorsViewModel
  {
  public Movies mvz { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Actors> act { get; set; }
  }
```

If anyone having expertise in this regard is reading this post, kindly guide me with the correct logic or any other approach that helps me get the result.

Comment: Your view does not even compile (because `act` is a collection). Its not clear what your trying to do, but I assume you want to display a `Movie` and then select one of more `Actor` (using a Listbox or via checkboxes)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `foreach` loop for `act`like below.

I'm not sure about the syntax, because its very long back I have work on MVC, But you can refer the logic.

```
@foreach (var item in a.act)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(@item.Id)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(@item.Id, new { @class = "form-control" })
}
```